# Inversion of BDD

Tags: algorithms, logic, binary-trees

How can I write an algorithm which inverts a 2-level BDD? It should take as input a 2L-level quasi-reduced BDD rooted at $r$ encoding a relation $R : B^L → 2^{B^L}$ and returns the 2L-level quasi-reduced BDD rooted at $s$ encoding the relation $R^{−1} : B^L →2^{B^L}$, that is, $j \in R(i) \iff i \in R^{−1}(j)$.

Comment: I dont understand how to start. Its not a inverse of values, it is an inverse of the structure of BDD, and i cannot get a clear picture of how to write the pesudocode.

Comment: Try working out a few cases - take some BDDs and try to invert them by hand.